# I am trying to segment the list and then remove duplicates according to the given input values ? However I am missing something

Tags: python, string

There are 2 inputs given

1. A string at **N** length.
2. An integer **k** that satisfies the condition : **N % k = 0**

For instance :

**"AABCAAADA"**

**3**

In this case I need to *divide string into (9/3) 3 subparts* and then *I need to remove the duplicates*.

[explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRbni.png) -> you can see the demonstration here.

I wrote a code that does the exact thing, however at the end of my output section I see "None".
I couldn't figure out where did that come from..

Here is my code:

```
s = "AABCAAADA"
k = 3
def merge_the_tools(string, k):
    ls = segment(string,k)
    for l in ls:
        print(remove_repetitive(l))

def remove_repetitive(string):
    temp = list(dict.fromkeys(string))
    return "".join(temp)


def segment(string,k):
    ls = []
    segment_len = int(len(string) / k)
    x = 0
    for i in range(segment_len):
        ls.append(string[x:x+k])
        x += k
    return ls

print(merge_the_tools(s,k))
```

And this is my output:

```
AB
CA
AD
None
```

Comment: `merge_the_tools` returns `None` and you're printing its output, just call the method without the `print` statement.

Comment: well that actually worked thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```s
k = 3

new = [s[((x+1)*3)-3:(x+1)*3] for x in range(k)]

new = list(map(set, new))

print(new)

>>> ({'B', 'A'}, {'C', 'A'}, {'D', 'A'})
```

This line `[((x+1)*3)-3:(x+1)*3]` just gets the next three items and makes a list out of them and adds it to the overall list.

This line `list(map(set, new))` just removes duplicates from each list.

Comment: yes, indeed, first I made it this way but the problem is when we make it set then we don't have the control over the sequence of the letters. In which case the output result returns wrong for the answer. But thanks anyways.